# SSIS ForEachLoop Container Failed to load data to table when Execute from SSMS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have SSIS ForEachLoop container to get file name and file path from sharing folder and save it on table called `FileInfo`.
When I try to run on Visual Studio, it works perfectly fine and load the table with File Name, File Path and Date.
[image: SSIS PACKAGE]

But when i Deploy it to SSMS and try to run it from SSMS, it does not load the table with any information, so the table is empty and it caused an error on the next process which getting data from the table.
Fortunately, other packages is run perfectly when i try it on SSMS.

I use Visual Studio 2012.

For the deployment method, I use right click on Package name and click deploy and choose server and path like picture below.

[image]

Is there any missing configuration or setting?

Please Help me, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you run it from SSMS, open the reports from the SSIS node. I suspect you'll find an OnInformation, I think,  event telling you that the ForEach enumerator found no results.

"Fun" fact, the Enumerator being unable to access a location *isn't* an error. It's more like a .net foreach loop when presented with an empty enumerable. "Oh, it's empty, I guess there's no work to be done." Instead of "There might be work to be done but I can't see what's in the folder"

The top 3 reasons for this, Foreach-works-on-my-machine-but-not-the-server, are

1. Permissions. The location to be enumerated cannot be accessed by the account that is running the package. That tends to be the most common based on my experience. In your cased, what is the path to the Employee or Vendor file? I commonly see people posting things like `C:\user\Jeff\Documents\ImportantStuff` which you have access to but if I were to run the same package on your machine, it would "fail" because I don't have access. But of course, not really fail because the enumerator is empty and goes on to the next task. The resolution is  to either move the source data to a folder the SSIS user will be able to access or log on to the target server and set the ACL appropriately for the user.
2. Path doesn't exist. In development, all local file work was rooted at `C:\ssisdata` At the server level, that became `D:\ssisdata` By not having a C:\SSISData on the servers, that provided us a quick test to ensure configurations were in force and I *think* a path not existing yields the same empty enumerator as insufficient permissions.
3. Mapped drives. Similar to the previous Path doesn't exist, this is Path-doesn't-exist-because-magic. At many organizations, they attach a shared drive to each users computer so they can share files between users, have strong backup policies, etc. H: is a common one at the companies I've consulted with because a mnemonic of H = Home drive. As part of the user login experience, a script runs and mounts a network drive which is really `\\server\share\` to the H drive letter. Except, service accounts which are commonly used for things like running SQL Server don't have those. To resolve this, either people change the H:\ssisdata path to \server\share\ssisdata or they add a precursor/successor task to mount the drive and then unmount the drive. I've seen that done as both Execute Package Tasks as well as baked into SQL Agent job steps. Given your intention to right click and run, I suspect the former would be a better fit for you. And of course, after switching from mapped drive to UNC, you might still hit the permission issue because computers are fun.

Comment: Hi, My path for the folder is `\\server\Production\Employee_Data or Vendor_Data`
After I deploy, I try to run the package from SSIDB from my Local and it happen i said above. I wonder, if I run the package from Local via SSISDB, does the user account that run the process is my local account or not? Because i believe my local account has permission to the folder